# How to Get Different Response Body from Server in Android with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, response

so I have this JSON samples here, I have three kinds of response:

```
{"status": "00",
 "message": "Successfully Registered!"}

{"status": "02",
 "message": "Register is failed, the data is not available"}

{"status": "03",
 "message": "Register is failed, the data already exists"}
```

What I want to ask here is that when I want to do POST data to the server, I want that one of the JSON lines will appear instead of the regular response code such as "200" or "400".  When I try it on the postman, the body will display one of the JSON lines above, but when I try to insert data from the android application, it shows me the regular response one. How can I get the custom code prepared by the server and display it through *Toast.maketext()* instead of the "Actual" response.body()?

Here is the link for my POJO class:
https://pastebin.com/xKNz3GW9

and here is the link for the method I used to POST the data;

```
public void registrationNewUser(Regisresponse regisresponse){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        String tokens = preferences.getString("userToken",null);
        Call<Regisresponse> call = apiService.regisUser("Bearer " + tokens,regisresponse);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Regisresponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Regisresponse> call, retrofit2.Response<Regisresponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    try {
                        if(response.body()!=null)
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this," response message success " + response.code(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(response.errorBody()!=null)
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this," response message error " + response.code(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Regisresponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR : ", t.getMessage());
//                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Please kindly help me to solve this, cause I also new to handling different response like this :)) Thank you

Comment: It would be better if you add whole example in JSON (with other fields), it's not clear what answer you're getting. Why don't you add "status" and "message" to your POJO class? Then you can get your code in a Toast with response.body().getMessage(), since with "response.body()" you get your POJO instance

Comment: If in response you get just "status" and "message" you shouldn't pass your "Regisresponse" as a returning type to you apiService. It should be another POJO class with just "status" and "message".

Comment: @sergiytikhonov about the JSON, I only get the endpoint and not the whole code of its backend, so that's why I can't just mix the status and message into one with Regisresponse. Besides that, the "status" and "message" should be in one POJO class, because based on the server-side, they didn't have the Regisresponse variables on its code, so basically both of them are separated. And that makes me confused about how to exactly get the custom response.  Also, when I try it via Postman, it is actually working perfectly fine like when post the data then that JSON custom code will appear

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand your thought. I don't need get into backend code, I just asked to show response they send - actually you see it in Postman. Are there only two field you've shown?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov yes, the postman only show "status" and "message"

Comment: Then just add new POJO class with these two fields and change type returning by your apiService.regisUser to this class instead of Regisresponse. So you'll have one POJO class for request structure (your Regisresponse)  and another - for response. There are changes to your backend needed, it's just a help to retrofit to get proper structure from incoming JSON

Comment: I've meant "There are NO changes to your backend needed" in last comment, sorry )

Comment: you can easily create a POJO class from your response Json [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Use this class as your response class.

Comment: @sergiytikhonov I already created 2 POJO class and each of them contains regisresponse and response . When I do POST data, it should be calling regisresponse class right? and also in the call retrofit, I should call the regisresponse right? so how can I call the response POJO to get the response

Comment: @AkashBisht I've created two pojo class each for the response status and the form itself

Comment: You should use Call<ResponseClass> not Call<Regisrepsonse>

Comment: @AkashBisht  but in my interface class it requires Regisresponse instead of responseclass

Comment: @AkashBisht or it should be like this? https://pastebin.com/r5Xt9dhf

Comment: okay, I got it @AkashBisht Thank you